# How to reduce the process delay using VHDL in xilinx

Tags: vhdl, xilinx

For the code i wrote, i am giving my 19 samples of a sine signal by pasting them in the testbench, i am using a process in the code where i am doing all the calculation i want to do, but in the simulator, its showing like it is taking a lot of time (approx. 19ms) to calulate the output. help me to eliminate this delay.
 Below is the picture where top field is clock, next three are inputs and then we have three outputs, and lastly the time period. here 220 is the max. range i gave to the output.[image]
 code:

```
entity trial_6 is
generic( width    : integer := 18);
 Port   ( clk      : in  std_logic;
          V1,V2,V3 : in integer range -220 to 220;
         Va,Vb,Vc : out integer range -220 to 220);
end trial_6;

architecture Behavioral of trial_6 is

  type memory is array(0 to width-1) of integer range -220 to 220;
  signal REG_1 : memory :=(others=>0);         
  signal REG_2 : memory :=(others=>0);         
  signal REG_3 : memory :=(others=>0);         
begin
  process(clk,REG_1,REG_2,REG_3)
    variable flag      : integer range 0 to width := 0;
  begin

    if rising_edge(clk) then                            
        REG_1(flag) <= V1;
         REG_2(flag) <= V2;
         REG_3(flag) <= V3;
        flag := flag + 1;

    if (flag = width) then                              

      Va <= ((REG_1(0) + REG_2(0) + REG_3(0))/3);

      Vb <= ((REG_1(0) + REG_2(5) + REG_3(11))/3); 

      Vc <= ((REG_1(0) + REG_2(11)+ REG_3(5))/3);


      flag := 0;
    end if;
    end if;
  end process;

end Behavioral;
```

test bench:- i have used clock period of 1.11 ms
[image]

Comment: Use a faster clock.

Comment: What exactly do you want your code to do?

Comment: i want to find out the three phase sequence components of any balanced or unbalanced three phase power supply. please suggest me that i can do as latter on i also have to take inputs directly from ADC, and this ADC will be getting its input from any function generator or other source.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned, the clock you use in your testbench is certainly not matching the clock you have in your actual design. The time it takes the process to deliver your result is directly depending on your clockrate.

Comment: i took 18 samples, and input signal frequency is 50 Hz, therefore sampling frequency=inp. freq. * no. of samples = 900Hz. so sampling time is 1/900=1.11 ms..So is there anything else i can do to improvise with inp. freq. =50Hz and samples 18?

Comment: What exactly bothers you? I don't understand why you're using a clock frequency of only 50Hz. The fact that you have a 50Hz sine doesn't mean your process cannot run at a higher frequency. By the way, you can remove REG_1, REG_2 and REG_3 from your sensitivity list but may should consider adding a reset signal.

Comment: 50 Hz because normally we use 50 Hz freq. in our power supply, thats it. the no. of samples can be varried.

Answer (score 3):

You won't be able to eliminate the delay entirely as this is fundamental to the code that you have posted.

The variable flag is updated every Rising edge of clk as is REG_1, REG_2 and REG_3. When the value of flag = width (which is 18 in this case) the outputs Va, Vb and Vc are updated with the values from the calculations. As flag starts from 0 this will cause this update to happen after exactly 19 clock cycles.

This delay is necessary to allow the REG_1, 2 and 3 to be populated with the incoming sample values. You could reduce the delay to 12 by altering the width generic as the element in your calculations is REG_3(11). However, it is likely this would have implications for the wider system as this width may be chosen deliberately.
You could also change the Flag = width comparison for Flag = 12.

Or you could use a faster clock which will retain the number of clock cycles but will reduce the absolute latency.

Comment: i have given test bench inputs as given in the picture, is it possible to somehow input all of them instantaneously at one point of time?